# list.files() -recursive argument not working sometime?

Tags: r

When I run list.files on a directory, I get the following results.

```
> list.files(file_path)
[1] "folder 1"   "folder 2"
```

Within these folders I know that there are other folders, and I want to get their folder names as well. So I run list.files with recursive = T, but this is the result I get.

```
> list.files(file_path, recursive = TRUE)
character(0)
```

What is the reason for this? Is the recursive argument broken? I've banged my head against the wall for over an hour trying to figure it out. The command line and Python have no problem with the specified directory. It's just R and the list.files() command that won't work.

Comment: What OS? What is the path you're listing?

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but turns out if the last nested folder is empty, then $list.files(x, recursive = T)$ returns null. I just wan't aware of that behavior and thought that it would still return the nested folder names